# Looping Through ARRAY elements in SQL Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have defined an array in a procedure with 4 elements in it. How can I loop through these elements in snowflake SQL procedure. I can get the length of ARRAY, but how to read each element in loop,

```
DECLARE
   NUM_LIST ARRAY :=[1,2,3,4];
   Len INT;
BEGIN           
   Len := ARRAY_SIZE(NUM_LIST);     
END;
```

Tried For loop with length

```
FOR I IN 1 TO ARRAY_SIZE(:NUM_LIST)
DO
  INSERT INTO TEST VALUES((GET(:NUM_LIST,:I)));
END FOR;
```

Getting below error,

> SQL Error [2014] [22000]: Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 710 at position 18 : SQL compilation error:
> Invalid expression [GET(CAST(PARSE_JSON(:NUM_LIST) AS ARRAY), 1)] in VALUES clause

Answer (score 2):

Two pointers:

1. `INSERT INTO VALUES` expects constants or simple expression -> using `INSERT INTO SELECT`
2. Array's index is 0-based.

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST(i INT);

DECLARE
   NUM_LIST ARRAY :=[1,2,3,4];
BEGIN           
   FOR I IN 0 TO ARRAY_SIZE(:NUM_LIST)-1
   DO
     INSERT INTO TEST(I) SELECT GET(:NUM_LIST,:I);
   END FOR;
END;
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST;
-- I
-- 1
-- 2
-- 3
-- 4
```

---

FOR loop is not required and entire operation could be performed as single `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement:

```
DECLARE
   NUM_LIST ARRAY :=[1,2,3,4];
BEGIN           
    INSERT INTO TEST(I)
    SELECT s.VALUE
    FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT=>:NUM_LIST)) AS s;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value from array into variable and then use that variable in insert statement, As snowflake don't know what's stored in array it prevents by synatx to keep get clause inside values()

Just one more thing, your loop should start with 0,  as nsnowflake array starts with index 0.

```
DECLARE
   NUM_LIST ARRAY :=[1,2,3,4];
   Len INT;
BEGIN           
   Len := ARRAY_SIZE(NUM_LIST); 
   FOR I IN 0 TO ARRAY_SIZE(:NUM_LIST)-1
    DO
    let val int := GET(:NUM_LIST,:I);
      INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(:val);
    END FOR;
END;
```